# How to test string with regular expression in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have URL link like "images.myweb.com/files" OR "test.com/images" 

I want to check if URL contains like 
**".com/" or ".in/" or ".net/" or ".org/"** with regular expression .

How it possible with C# regular expression..

Comment: So, you want a regular expression even if it is not the best thing for the job? It is better to ask _what_ it the best way to achieve what you need instead of telling people _how_ to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lst is your string lists (like `lst = new []{".com/" , ".in/" ,".net/" ,".org/"}`) then you can do it with Linq:

```
lst.Any(x=>myString.Contains(x))
```

and if you want your string end with this items do:

```
lst.Any(x=>myString.EndsWith(x))
```

Answer (score 5):

don't use a Regex, simply use an [`URI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)  class wih a [`String.EndsWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz.aspx)

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com:8080/images");
  bool isCom = baseUri.Host.EndsWith(".com");
  bool isNet= baseUri.Host.EndsWith(".net");
  bool isOrg = baseUri.Host.EndsWith(".org");
```

perhaps combined with a [String.ToLower()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower.aspx) to bypass case sensitivity.

Comment: Using your example, what happens with `www.computer.nl`?